# DialogFlow/Api.AI inline editor regex for email validation

Tags: regex, validation, dialogflow-es

https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-regex-nodejs

shows an easy way to perform a regex validation, however I haven't succeeded in creating one for email addresses.

from the original regex i changed the pattern to [^\s]*@[a-z0-9.-]

changed the dialogflow parameter to email with $email and kept the rest the same.

```
function validateEmployeeID (agent) {
// get the employee ID parameter from the request header received from Dialogflow

let email = agent.parameters.email;
let pattern = /[^\s]*@[a-z0-9.-]/;
if (email.match(pattern) !== null) 
{ agent.add(`Email is wrong, please provide a valid email address.`); } 
else { agent.add(agent.request_.body.queryResult.fulfillmentText); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some research, I have had success with this regex

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$
```

more info here for others interested; https://blog.dialogflow.com/post/validate-entities-using-regular-expressions-in-fulfillment/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create a regex for email validation then there are lots of links available.
You may try the below one from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-validate-email-address-regex/).

```
/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9-]+.+.[A-Z]{2,4}/igm
```

and test it online [here](https://www.regextester.com/)